# Hibernate prepareStatement doesn't work

Tags: hibernate

I used to have this url connection in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and everything worked fine.

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:address.to.real.db</property>
```

Now, I changed the URL like this to learn the code locally.

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mock_db</property>
```

After the change, the statement below won't work anymore. 
It throws an exception saying `Invalid schema name: TEST in statement`

```
jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(parameterizedStrQuery);
```

In my hibernate mapping xml file I have this line of code

```
<hibernate-mapping schema="TEST">
```

parameterizedStrQuery looks like this

```
select obj.obj_id, from test.obj where obj.foo=0 and obj.var = 1 and (obj.obj_id in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: So you are just using hibernate to get a jdbc connection rather than using a hibernate query?  Could you show the content of `parameterizedStrQuery`?

Comment: I modified my posting to add the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_schemas_schema_objects

> In HyperSQL, there is only one catalog per database. The name of the
>   catalog is PUBLIC. You can rename the catalog with the ALTER CATALOG
>   RENAME TO statement. All schemas belong the this catalog. The catalog
>   name has no relation to the file name of the database.

So I would try to open your `mock_db` and rename the catalog from `PUBLIC` to `TEST`.